# How to display datetime value in API response with gorm

Tags: postgresql, datetime, go, go-gorm

I am building simple API with Golang and I am using gorm with Postgres.
I am storing datetime value with `time.Now()` in database and it stores it correctly.
When I am trying to display this value in API response I am getting `"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"` value.

Server logs:

```
(sql: Scan error on column index 5: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: []uint8 -> *time.Time)
[2016-06-03 22:41:22]
```

GetAll func:

```
func GetAll() map[string]*Project {
    db, err := NewDB()
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    Projects = make(map[string]*Project)
    projects := []Project{}
    db.Find(&projects)

    for i := range projects {
        fmt.Println(i, &projects[i])
        v := &projects[i]
        Projects[v.PackageName] = &projects[i]
    }
    return Projects
}
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Have you tried passing `parseTime=True` in the DSN? For example, `gorm.Open("postgres", "...?charset=utf8&parseTime=true")`

Comment: No, I have this line:
 
"""
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=postgres dbname=go_dev sslmode=disable")
"""
I didn't find a way how to pass this parameter to the Open func